# How to query by unfixed keys in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb-query

I have a collection, the document structure like:

```
{
  'visitors': {
    'name1': {
      age: 30,
      city: A,
      phone: XXX
    },
    'name2': {
      age: 26,
      city: A,
      phone: XXX
    },
  }
}
```

I want query visitors by city, or by age.
If the visitors stores as array, it is easy to query by "visitors.city", or "visitors.age". But it is a dict now, with visitor's name as key, how to query it?

Comment: It is better to change the structure. If you can't, use `$objectToArray`

Comment: Thanks, @nimrodserok, I will use $objectToArray convert object to array first, then query by visitors.v.city.